# Horizontal scrolling like vertical scrolling in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Vertical scrolling in IntelliJ IDEA works as we would expect: moving the viewport up and down. Horizontal scrolling, however, doesn't move the viewport, but rather it moves the cursor left and right.

How can I make horizontal scrolling move the viewport (like vertical scrolling does)?

If it matters, this is on a Dell Inspiron 5000 series laptop. The trackpad allows for scrolling in either direction by using two fingers. Programs like Firefox correctly move the viewport when scrolling horizontally.

Comment: From what I can tell, this is a bug in IntelliJ. Add your own comments to the bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115509

Comment: If you arrive here, please upvote @ArtOfWarfare's ticket. There's a "thumbs up" on the right side next to the text "voters".

Answer (score 12):

On Windows, SHIFT + scroll up/down should work, if it does not, you can add a key binding in the keymap. Open File > Settings > Keymap and search for "Scroll Left". Right click on the item and select add mouse shortcut and try swiping horizontally on your trackpad, if it does not detect, you can hold SHIFT and scroll up or down depending on your preference. Repeat the same for "Scroll right". Tested on Windows 10 Enterprise build 1803 on Surface Book 2.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not 100% solution but you can try to use touchpad scrolling while holding the SHIFT button.

In case you would have to provide some info on your OS and Idea version used, as I have a horizontal scrolling working on Linux.

If you are on Linux Ubuntu [Enable horizontal scrolling in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264091/enable-horizontal-scrolling-in-ubuntu) can be helpful.

Comment: The OS is Windows 8.1.

Comment: Holding shift doesn't change the behavior. I really think this is an IDEA issue, though, since horizontal scrolling works as expected in every other program I've tried (Firefox, File Explorer, Sublime Text).

Comment: Can also depend on which Java platform you have installed. Which version of Idea are you using ? you can try with the [EAP14 version](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP) to see if there is any change in behavior.

Comment: IDEA version is 13.1.5. Java version is 1.8.0_20. I have smooth scrolling enabled and "prefer scrolling editor canvas to keep caret line centered".