# Two-Finger touchpad scroll not working on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll

I have Android Studio 3.1 and for some reason I am unable to scroll using the touchpad. I have to manually scroll by dragging the scroll bar on the right, and this can get very tedious and inconvenient if im working on a large project. I used to be able to two-finger scroll on previous versions of Android Studio but for some reason its just not working anymore. I have windows 10 if thats relevant. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem with touchpad one-finger scrolling on Android Studio 3.1.  Scrolling works pretty much everywhere else, so there should be something wrong with Android Studio.

Comment: How were you able to fix it? Even I am facing issue on my Lenovo laptop..and enabling the Smooth Scrolling does not help..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946565/16083654

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found a solution by making a small change to a registry entry:

1. Open regedit.exe using run
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> SOFTWARE -> Elantech -> Smartpad
3. Change ScrollControl_Mode from 0 to 1

I found the answer here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3lhmhq/win10_elan_touchpad_scrolling_issues/

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was looking for a solution for VS IDE; and this trick solves my problem. Fantastic!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just go to **File>Settings** or **Ctrl+Alt+S**. Then Select **Appearance** in **Appearance & Behavior** menu. Now Scroll down to **Windows option** and Select the **Smooth Scrolling** checkbox. Below there is an image. This worked for me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXApl.png

Comment: smooth scrolling is enabled.. maybe a linux problem

Answer (score 0):

Two-finger scrolling problem generally occurs due to malfunctioning of touchpad drivers of windows 10.

**Things you can try are:**

1. Go to `File`>`Settings` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Then Select *Appearance* in *Appearance & Behavior* menu. Now Scroll down to Windows option and select the *Smooth Scrolling* checkbox
   as suggested by @Nikhil
2. You have to update your touchpad drivers:

   **For updating driver**:

   1. Go to the Device Manager.
   2. Expand "Mice and other pointing devices".
   3. Right-click on your touchpad (probably Asus Support Device)
   4. Properties.
   5. Driver Tab.
   6. Roll Back Driver.
   7. Restart computer.
3. If it still doesn't work now try updating your touchpad driver again after rolling back.
4. If it still doesn't work try to uninstall your touchpad driver and reinstall it.

**Important:** Always Remember to restart your computer every time you make any change.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is often caused by other apps that are currently running. For example cmd or OneNote. After closing those scrolling works again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any Microsoft word open in the background if so close it, the touch pad should be working fine after that